# How do (commensal and mutualist) microorganisms colonize the seminal vesicles?

Tags: human-biology, microbiology, human-physiology, health, pregnancy

Human's seminal fluid has it's own microbiome ([Javurek et al. 2016](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep23027)). How do species of this microbiome (bacteria and eukaryotes) colonize the seminal vesicles?

It is possible that different species would colonize the seminal fluid through different means. What are the possible ways by which such colonization could happen?